# Why are my display names disrupting labels in an editor template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, mvc-editor-templates

I'm using a loop as below to render a label and editor for each property on a view model:

```
@{
    var properties = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !pm.IsComplexType && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm));
}
    @foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        <li>
            <div class="form-line">
                @{
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml)
        {
                    @Html.Editor(prop.DisplayName ?? prop.PropertyName)
        }
        else
        {
                    @Html.Label((prop.IsRequired ? "* " : "") + (prop.DisplayName ?? prop.PropertyName))
                    @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
        }
                }
            </div>
        </li>
    }
```

And the model:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    [UIHint("DropDown", "MVC", "SelectListName", "StatusSelectList")]
    public Guid StatusId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Emp Number")]
    public string RefNum { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
```

When I use a display name of "Emp. No.", a label doesn't get rendered at all. When I use a display name of "Emp. Number", only a "Number" label gets rendered. Only when I use a display name of "Emp Number", without any full stops, does my full, expected label get rendered. What is going on here?

Comment: what are you looping through? the metadata?

Comment: @RPM1984 Yes. Please see now I have added the query for `properties` to my code above.

Comment: okay well i've never seen this before. Why would you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve? It looks quite messy

Comment: @RPM1984 It isn't really that messy at all. What I'm trying to achieve is to override the default layout for EditorForModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload of the Html.Label helper. The first argument represents an expression that will point to the editor so that the `for` attribute of the label points to the corresponding input field. The second argument allows you to set the label text. Try like this:

```
@Html.Label(prop.PropertyName, (prop.IsRequired ? "* " : "") + (prop.DisplayName ?? prop.PropertyName))
```

Comment: Ya, thanks @Darin. This is turning into quite the crash course on HTML generation in MVC3.